# NGINX and Zammad suddenly 502

Tags: nginx

So we installed zammad a while ago and it always worked like charm until yesterday when we suddenly got a 404 at first and than (without touching anything) a 502. I’ve seen another Post on here which is resolved but any of the steps in that post didn’t help me anything at all.

Not sure, how can i find out?
Used Zammad installation source: deb
Operating system: Ubuntu 18.04
Browser + version: Any

Expected behavior:
To work again like bevor

Actual behavior:
A 502 Bad Gateway

Steps to reproduce the behavior:
i don’t know

**Error log from /var/log/nginx/zammad.error.log looks like this**

```
2021/03/12 07:41:13 [error] 234787#234787: *17 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.22.152, server: support. solid.at, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: " support.solid.at"
```

I already tried:
Updated but only security updates, but zammad didn't work before that neither
Restarting all service - worked and all are up an running - done with `systemctl status zammad[tab][tab]`
and than `systemctl status` plus the service
Now i came to an error where i can't start nginx
if i run `nginx -t` i get the following which seams to me like a spelling error.
But i can't seem to figure it out.

```
root@zammad:/etc/nginx/sites-available# nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "n /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/searchindex:rebuild:1
```

Comment: Please add output of `nginx -T` to the post.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen the Output is at the bottom

Comment: That is not `nginx -T`, notice the capital letter.

Comment: Ok i get this when i run nginx -T

Comment: [warn] 24959#24959: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
2021/03/15 06:08:04 [emerg] 24959#24959: open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: You need to be root when running `nginx -T`. Make sure to add the output to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what did work for me, is to set up a new VM, made a backup of the old zammad db. Imported that into the new VM and all did work like a charm. Thanks for your help :)